# Copy chart from Excel to PowerPoint preserving quality and transparency

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I'm coding a macros to copy an Excel chart and paste it to a PowerPoint presentation as a **transparent** picture. Sounds simple so far, but the problem is that the picture is either not transparent or distorted.

Take a look please:

- here's the distorted version I get after executing my macros:

[image: distorted:]

- here's what I get when I manually copy/paste it (and that's how I want it to look like):

[image: desired:]

My code (the relevant part):

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("MyChartNameGoesHere").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
Set PPApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
Set PPPres = PPApp.ActivePresentation
Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex)
PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteEnhancedMetafile).Select
```

I've tried to change the `CopyPicture` format parameter from *xlPicture* to *xlBitmap* but in that case the picture is not transparent and overlays slide background. And I'm not sure it looks smooth.

I've also tried to change the slide's `PasteSpecial` parameter to almost each listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa212207%28v=office.11%29.aspx) and still no success.

For some time I believed that the *xlBitmap* version is OK and it's just not transparent. That's why I moved both examples to the edge of a slide so we can see that. But then after zooming in I realised it was distorted as well. I don't know whether I got really mistaken or I just accidentally dropped something important from my code (most likely). Restored by memory to the previous version but failed.

Once again, everything's fine when I copy chart from Excel and special-paste it to PowerPoint as a picture manually. PowerPoint 2007 doesn't have a macros recorder, so I can't see what's happening.

Please help me out. Any thoughts are mush appreciated!

**UPDATE** the "distorted" version is not only... distorted, but also 5 times "heavier" (in terms of a presentation file size). Any help still much appreciated!

Comment: Excel 2007 does have a macro recorder.  Enable the developer ribbon - Office button - Excel Options - Show developer tab in the Ribbon.

Comment: Oh man I'm sorry, I meant PowerPoint 2007 :) Thanks for the info, question edited.

Answer (score 0):

I use in my work this code to charts

```
For Each Grf In E.ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    Grf.Copy
    Sld.Shapes.Placeholders(Nr).Select msoCTrue
    P.ActivePresentation.Windows(1).View.PasteSpecial (ppPasteMetafilePicture)
    Nr = Nr + 1
Next Grf
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try that a bit later.